# My wordpress doesnt show up

Tags: installation

I installed wordpress on local host. But it only showed up the first time. As i turned my laptop off and on it didn't show up. I reinstalled it but the same thing happened.

Comment: You need to provide more details.  Also, did you restart your local server when you rebooted? (MAMP, XAMP, etc)?

Comment: No. I didn't. It's on xamp by the way.

Comment: I guess what I meant to say was, make sure your local server is running after rebooting.  I believe with XAMP you have to tell it to restart automatically after a reboot.  What errors are you getting, etc?

Comment: You need to turn the server on to use it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Ubuntu type linux you can install WordPress easily by this script .

If you want to check you can go on this link[select properly](https://github.com/vanpariyar/my-shell-script)

It is my official GitHub repository.

Thanks for reaching out.